# Attempt to convert object to generic type results with FS0013 error

Tags: f#

I am trying to cast `obj` to `'T` and I receive FS0013 error in compile time.
What is wrong with my code?
Maybe it is broken because I tried to "map" it from C# and this is done in completely different way in F#?

```
let myFunc (x : Option<'T>) =
        match x with
            None -> failwith "wtf"
            | Some x -> Convert.ChangeType(x, typedefof<'T>) :> 'T
```

Full error text:

> error FS0013: The static coercion from type
>       `obj`
>   to 
>       `'T`
>    involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Static coercions are not allowed on some types. Further type  annotations are needed.

**UPDATE:**
This is the actual function I am trying to write. `Option`'s value is used in case I don't have my own value.

```
let ( %? ) (defaultValue : Option<'a>) (parameterName : string) 
                        = match (environVar parameterName) with
                            null -> match defaultValue with
                                    None -> failwith "No value found as well as default value is not set"
                                    | Some defaultVal -> defaultVal
                            | x -> let objectResult = Convert.ChangeType(x, typedefof<'a>)
                                   objectResult :> 'a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to convert !

Just write:

```
  | Some x -> x
```

Then your function is generic.
The pattern match has already decomposed the type and unwrapped the value from the option.
Don't confuse `obj` with generic `'T`.
A function returning an `obj` is not necessarily generic.

**EDIT**

After your update, you can use this:

```
objectResult :?> 'a
```

But you will have no run-time guaranties.

In F# `:>` means 'upcast' and `:?>` means 'downcast' (if you can). The former has compile-time checking that's why 'cast' is split in 2 different operations.

Comment: I tried to simplify my problem and it looks like I simplified it too much. I will post updated code in the question.

Comment: I updated the question, would appreciate if you could take a look.

Comment: And what's the return type of: ``environVar parameterName``

Comment: Ok, so how do you expect a string to be casted to any type ``T'``?

Comment: I expect it to be like C#: (bool)System.Convert.ChangeType("False", typeof(bool))

Comment: Oh god, it was so close. Thank you.